# Python script cronjob with external Library

Tags: python, cron, beautifulsoup

I'd like to run a Python script with external Library ([beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) on a hosted Webserver.

What type of Webserver do I need? I heard something about CGI?
How I've to implement and install the external library in my script and on the server?
Cronjob is only for PHP, isn't it? Is there a "cronjob" for Python?

Answer (score 1):

[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is an OS scheduler for unix like systems.  It allows you to run any command at set intervals.

Do you need a webserver, or do you just want to routinely execute your script?  If you just want to routinely execute your script there is no need for a webserver, cron will suffice.

I believe all you need is ssh access, and sudo access to a server.  (Amazon ec2 offeres free micro instances for a year)

After that you can install [pip, virtualenv](http://dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/), and beautiful soup.  You can then register your command (which just executes your script) with `cron` and you are all set

Comment: Okey, I've to specify my Idea:
I'd like to run a Python script routinely. Because I don't want to run my Computer all the time only for this tiny script, I'd like to us a "web server". I found a huge list on [freehostsfinder](http://www.freehostsfinder.com) with different typs of server. Which one do I need? How to run the script routinely on this server? How does it work with external libraries?

Comment: CanadaRunner , your question isn't clear.  Can you specify what you want done?  It almost sounds like you want to run a script on a cloud host, without booting up your machine.